# ASP.NET Oracle SQL query not properly ended?

Tags: asp.net, sql, oracle

I'm a newb to both ASP.NET and Oracle SQL.  I'm attempting to create one long SQL string (using `UNION ALL`) and then pass the string to a Data Handler class that takes care of the rest.  The problem certainly exists in my SQL string.

Here is the first section of my code, which runs flawlessly:

```
sql = "SELECT 'DCS - HCA (81)', HCA_SENT_DCS, HCA_VALID_DCS, HCA_SUSPEND_DCS, HCA_REJECTED_DCS,"
sql &= " SUM(HCA_VALID_DCS + HCA_SUSPEND_DCS + HCA_REJECTED_DCS) As ""Total Returned"","
sql &= " RESOLVED_CNT, SUM(HCA_REJECTED_DCS - RESOLVED_CNT) As ""To Do"""
sql &= " FROM HUB_CDI_CONTROL_NBRS WHERE REPORT_DATE = :0 "
_param.Add(dateSelected.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))
sql &= " GROUP BY HCA_SENT_DCS, HCA_VALID_DCS, HCA_SUSPEND_DCS, HCA_REJECTED_DCS,"
sql &= " RESOLVED_CNT"
```

However, when I try to `UNION` this SQL with another `SELECT` statement, I get the following exception:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Here is the full code:

```
sql = "SELECT 'DCS - HCA (81)', HCA_SENT_DCS, HCA_VALID_DCS, HCA_SUSPEND_DCS, HCA_REJECTED_DCS,"
sql &= " SUM(HCA_VALID_DCS + HCA_SUSPEND_DCS + HCA_REJECTED_DCS) As ""Total Returned"","
sql &= " RESOLVED_CNT, SUM(HCA_REJECTED_DCS - RESOLVED_CNT) As ""To Do"""
sql &= " FROM HUB_CDI_CONTROL_NBRS WHERE REPORT_DATE = :0 "
sql &= " GROUP BY HCA_SENT_DCS, HCA_VALID_DCS, HCA_SUSPEND_DCS, HCA_REJECTED_DCS,"
sql &= " RESOLVED_CNT"

sql &= " UNION ALL"

sql &= "SELECT 'SFDC - HCA (82)', HCA_SENT_SFDC, HCA_VALID_SFDC, HCA_SUSPEND_SFDC, HCA_REJECTED_SFDC,"
sql &= " SUM(HCA_VALID_SFDC + HCA_SUSPEND_SFDC + HCA_REJECTED_SFDC) As ""Total Returned"","
sql &= " RESOLVED_CNT, SUM(HCA_REJECTED_SFDC - RESOLVED_CNT) As ""To Do"""
sql &= " FROM HUB_CDI_CONTROL_NBRS WHERE REPORT_DATE = :0 "
sql &= " GROUP BY HCA_SENT_SFDC, HCA_VALID_SFDC, HCA_SUSPEND_SFDC, HCA_REJECTED_SFDC,"
sql &= " RESOLVED_CNT"

_param.Add(dateSelected.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))
_DH.TheSQL = sql
_DT = _DH.GetTableWithParameters(_param.ToArray)
```

I am concerned with two parts of this code:

1. Am I correctly calling the _param.Add() function?  Since I'm referencing the parameter twice, using `:0`, do I only have to use the _param.Add() function once?
2. I feel that I'm incorrectly using the `GROUP BY` syntax.  Oracle yelled at me when I tried to run queries without using `GROUP BY`, but I'm unsure if I'm using them correctly.  Essentially, I just added each column I `SELECTed` to `GROUP BY`

Otherwise, I am sure there are other errors I am missing.  Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: It may be much easier to recognise problems by getting the SQL statement working first outside of your asp.net application. Also after a quick glance you need a space after UNION ALL or before the next select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sql &= " UNION ALL"
sql &= "SELECT 'SFDC - HCA (82)', HCA_SENT_SFDC, HCA_VALID_SFDC, HCA_SUSPEND_SFDC, HCA_REJECTED_SFDC,"
```

Results in, somewhere in the middle:

```
... UNION ALLSELECT 'SFDC - HCA (82)', HCA_SENT_SFDC, ...
```

Note: "UNION **ALLSELECT**"

---

The full code with other fixes. I don't believe you actually wanted to GROUP BY, to add/subtract, you DON'T need the SUM() function.  To be valid in a UNION ALL, all columns of the first part must be named/aliased.

```
sql = "SELECT 'DCS - HCA (81)' Title, HCA_SENT_DCS, HCA_VALID_DCS, HCA_SUSPEND_DCS, HCA_REJECTED_DCS,"
sql &= " HCA_VALID_DCS + HCA_SUSPEND_DCS + HCA_REJECTED_DCS As ""Total Returned"","
sql &= " RESOLVED_CNT, HCA_REJECTED_DCS - RESOLVED_CNT As ""To Do"""
sql &= " FROM HUB_CDI_CONTROL_NBRS WHERE REPORT_DATE = :0 "
sql &= " UNION ALL "
sql &= "SELECT 'SFDC - HCA (82)', HCA_SENT_SFDC, HCA_VALID_SFDC, HCA_SUSPEND_SFDC, HCA_REJECTED_SFDC,"
sql &= " HCA_VALID_SFDC + HCA_SUSPEND_SFDC + HCA_REJECTED_SFDC As ""Total Returned"","
sql &= " RESOLVED_CNT, HCA_REJECTED_SFDC - RESOLVED_CNT As ""To Do"""
sql &= " FROM HUB_CDI_CONTROL_NBRS WHERE REPORT_DATE = :1 "

_param.Add(dateSelected.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))
_param.Add(dateSelected.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))  ' 2nd one
_DH.TheSQL = sql
_DT = _DH.GetTableWithParameters(_param.ToArray)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  The error was indeed the missing space between `UNION ALL` and `SELECT`.  Also, I removed all the `SUM` functions and used regular operators `+` and `-` instead.  Now, I don't have to use the `GROUP BY` clause.